# stream() vs. parallelStream() when adding in an ArrayList

Tags: java-8, parallel-processing, functional-programming, java-stream

I had this piece of code

```
List<UserNotification> userNotifications = new ArrayList<UserNotification>();

teatreAlertNotifications
            .parallelStream()
            .forEach(can -> userNotifications.add(new UserNotification(can)));
```

But since ArrayList is unsynchronized I think it is  bad practice and I should use .stream() instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or just:

```
List<UserNotification> userNotifications = teatreAlertNotifications
           .parallelStream()
           .map(UserNotification::new)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is called un-needed side effects, that are generally discouraged in the documentation.

You could keep your original code,  but use a synchronized data structure (thread safe), but in this case the order of the elements is not guaranteed.

Comment: be aware that UserNotification needs an argument

Comment: @carlesxuriguera it will use that argument... I don't get your point, this is the equivalent of `can -> new UserNotification(can)`